# Tile layout with CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, layout

Without relying on tables, what would be a good solution to accomplish a tile layout such as this: [image: tile layout] that automatically adapts to the screen size of the user. That is, the whole screen should be filled by the tiles, regardless of the with and height of the resolution.

I appreciate any ideas.

~ Robert

Comment: My example is here: http://shaquin.tk/experiments/tile.html. @MajoB was obviously writing their example at the same time as me.

Comment: Thanks Shaquin. All I tried so far was related to a table layout since I face problems with arranging the floated divs. I did not pay attention to the fact that float right must come before float left.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a working example:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PpdzE/)

Html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="first">first</div><div class="third">third</div>
<div class="second">second</div><div class="fourth">fourth</div><div class="last">last</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
html, body, .container
{
    height: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
}

.first {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: red;
}

.second{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: green;
}


.third{
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.fourth {
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

.last{
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

​

Comment: You beat me to it by 9 mins! :-)

Comment: I also want to thank you for your solution. Why don't you use absolute positioning as for example Shaquin in his example above?

Comment: @orschiro Because that wasn't necessary:)

Comment: @orschiro - You either have to use `float` or absolute positioning. Absolute positioning is more flexible, e.g. you can make certain elements overlap with the help of `z-index`.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with some `div` using [absolute positionning](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/absolutepositioning). And specify for each tile the width/height/top/left using `%` unit.

Comment: Probably the easiest and best solution all-around. It dosen't play nice when screen space is small, though, so consider using a fallback for small screens.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- Use a "content div" with 100% of width and height
- Use into the "content div" two divs: one for the left column and one for the right one. Remember to give those "%" dimension (to "content" div also)
- Remember that a floated right div have to come ***BEFORE*** a left floated div

With this three point, you should be able to try yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**

This will not mean the needs of your project. That has been answered alread by other uses.

---

For future reference, I would look into an oocss-approach to layout classes. You may have pages that have a different amount of tiles, etc. I use the following for my projects.

## Tiles Object

Used for creating tile layouts.

**css**

```
.tiles
{
    display: block;
}

.tiles__item
{
    display: block;

    height: auto;

    float:left;
}

.tiles--2
{
    margin-left: -4%;
}

.tiles--3
{
   margin-left: -2%;
}

.tiles--4
{
    margin-left: -2%;
}

.tiles--2 .tiles__item
{
    margin-left: 4%;

    width: 46%;
}

.tiles--3 .tiles__item
{
    margin-left: 2%;

    width: 31.3%;
}

.tiles--4 .tiles__item
{
    margin-left: 2%;

    width: 23%;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="tiles tiles--2">

    <div class="tiles__item">

    </div>

    <div class="tiles__item">

    </div>

</div>
```

## Dock Object

Docks content to the edge of the screen.

**css**

```
.dock 
{
    position: absolute;

    height: auto; 

    width: auto;
}

.dock--t
{
    width: 100%;

    top: 0;
}

.dock--b
{
    width: 100%;

    bottom: 0;
}

.dock--l
{
    height: 100%;

    left: 0;
}

.dock--r
{
    height: 100%;

    right: 0;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="dock dock--t">

    The content will be docked to the top of the screen.

</div?
```

## Other Ones

I would look at the Tiles object in the Metro UI Framework. They allow for heights

http://metroui.org.ua/

If you are looking for a good layout system that uses proportions:

https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki/Grids